# In Swift, How to check if the first element of an Array is equal to a list of values?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift5

Hi I'm a newbie here and I want to check if the first element of an Array is equal to a list of values. For example to check if a list of letters (chars) begins with a vowel.

something like this:

```
var listOfLetters = ["A","C","D","E","L"]
func firstItemIsVowel ( listOfLetters: [String] ) -> Boolean {
   if listOfLetters.first == ("A" or "E" or "I" or "O" or "U") {
   } Return True
}
```

Comment: Use `return listOfStrings.contains(listOfLetters.first)`, but first unwrap the Optional `listOfLetters.first`.

Comment: Perfect ! thank you so much @Starsky ! I was thinking in opposite ways

Comment: Please don’t edit the solution into the question, add an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have many of something and you want to know whether your target is among them, the search is far more efficient if you use a *set*.

```
let lettersToLookFor = Set("AEIOU")
```

You also have to be careful in *this* example to specify whether we are talking here about *characters* or *strings*. I have chosen to let `lettersToLookFor` be a set of *characters*.

Now the question is easy to answer using `contains`:

```
let listOfLetters : [Character] = ["A","C","D","E","L"]
let ok = lettersToLookFor.contains(listOfLetters[0]) // true
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Of course it would. The OP failed to specify anything about that. We have no idea what the goal is; one can go only by what we are told. I answered about the "in a list" part, no more.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. The list of letters and vowels was just an example. What I want to to do was to compare the first element of an array with a set as proposed in the answer above. I wanted to check if the first item of an array corresponded to any elements of a list. Thank you for the Answer, it worked just fine !

Comment: I changeds the title to be more generic "a list of values"

Comment: @LeoDabus To clarify, I have abolished the term "vowels" from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So after the answer and contributions thanks @matt @Starsky - here is a new version of the exemple of checking if the first letter of an array of Chars is a Vowel:

```
let vowelsSet =  Set("aeiou")
// let vowelArray = ["a","e","i","o","u"] // if you wish to use an array instead
var arrayOfRandomLetters : [Character] = ["o","c","d","e","l"]

func firstCharacterIsAVowel (_ arrayOfLetters: [Character]) -> Bool {
  if vowelsSet.contains(arrayOfRandomLetters.first!){
    return true
  } else { return false }
}
print(firstCharacterIsAVowel(arrayOfRandomLetters)) // true
```